# Element 'ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32' is already used with @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList

Tags: java, xml, simpleframework, парсер

Пытаюсь написать парсер xml .
вот так выглядит xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ServiceDataModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <DataTypeName>Msa_12331</DataTypeName>
        <Producer>1</Producer>
        <DataValues>
            <ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32>
                <Key>F_014110</Key>
                <Value>1</Value>
            </ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32>
            <ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32>
                <Key>F_014110110</Key>
                <Value>20</Value>
            </ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32>
            <ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32>
                <Key>F_014110120</Key>
                <Value>0</Value>
            </ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32>
        </DataValues>
    </ServiceDataModel>
```

поле ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32 не проходить и тут возникает ошибка парсера а именно  `Element 'ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32' is already used with @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList`

я создал java - класс по XSD ,  и там пытаюсь поле ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32 сделать `@ElementArray`,

кусок кода от парсера:

```
public static class DataValues {

        @ElementList(name = "ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32", required = true)
        private ArrayList<ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32> ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32;

        public ArrayList<Request.DataValues.ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32> getServiceDataStructModelOfInt32() {
            return ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32;
        }

        public void setServiceDataStructModelOfInt32(ArrayList<Request.DataValues.ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32> serviceDataStructModelOfInt32) {
            ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32 = serviceDataStructModelOfInt32;
        }

        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
                "key",
                "value"
        })

        public static class ServiceDataStructModelOfInt32 {

            @Element(name = "key", required = false)
            protected String key;
            @Element(name = "value", required = false)
            protected String value;


            public String getKey() {
                return key;
            }

            public void setKey(String key) {
                this.key = key;
            }

            public String getValue() {
                return value;
            }

            public void setValue(String value) {
                this.value = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

но компилятор java simpleframework exception выдает